# Creating relationship in Neo4j from a single csv file

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to load a single csv into a Neo4j DB. I have [followed this guideline](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/) but still can't understand why is not working for me.

I can create the nodes correctly (its attributes are all the columns but one) and I want to build a relationship between all the nodes with the only attribute left that wasn't added to the node.

My data in `file.csv` looks like:

> Column,instaGramId,imageDateCreated,imageTagCount,imageFilter,googleLabel_list
>   0,1165524631240624607_638926073,1453161384,7,Normal,"[cartoon, comics,
>   artwork]"
>   ...

I'm following these steps:

**Step 1: creating nodes** *this is working correctly*

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///file.csv" AS row 
CREATE (:Post {instaGramId: row.instaGramId,
    imageDateCreated: toInt(row.imageDateCreated),
    imageTagCount: row.imageTagCount,
    imageFilter: row.imageFilter});
```

*Only attribute left is `googleLabel_list` which needs to be a in a different node*

**Step 2: create an Index** *this is working correctly too, I guess*

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Post(instaGramId);
```

**Step 3: create relationships** *this is not working correctly*

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///file.csv" AS row
MATCH (post:Post {id: row.instaGramId})
MATCH (objects:Post {id: row.googleLabel_list})
MERGE (post)-[:CONTAINS_OBJECTS]->(objects);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following clause will probably never match anything (and therefore no relationships will ever be created):

```
MATCH (objects:Post {id: row.googleLabel_list})
```

This is because your existing `POST` nodes have `id` values (e.g., "1165524631240624607_638926073" -- which come from `row.instaGramId`) that probably look nothing like your `row.googleLabel_list` values (e.g., "[cartoon, comics, artwork]").

Comment: `MATCH (post:Post {id: row.instaGramId})` won't match anything either because the property is called `instaGramId`, not `id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind answers. I changed `id` for `instaGramId` but nothing is matching still. In order to create a relationship between columns of the same csv dataset, in the examples I saw they do this:

`USING PERIODIC COMMIT`    
`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:employees.csv" AS row`    
`MATCH (employee:Employee {employeeID: row.EmployeeID})`    
`MATCH (manager:Employee {employeeID: row.ReportsTo})`    
`MERGE (employee)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(manager);`

Comment: Maybe... do I have to create new nodes out of the `googleLabel_list` attributes?

Comment: Probably. But it depends on what you are actually trying to accomplish.